# Create (Team) Shared Drives using cell values as Drive Names on Google Drive using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I want to create multiple Shared Drives using cell values as Drive Names.

I can fetch the range's values but I dont know how to capture each values inside the array of arrays. I need to get those cell values to set the Drive Names.

Here is my code:

```
function createDriveID(){

var department = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var lastname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,2,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var firstname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(3,3,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

for (var i=0; i<department.length; i++ ) {
var dep = department[i].toString();
var dept = dep.substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
 //Logger.log(dept);


}

for (var x=0; x<lastname.length; x++) {
//var stri = lastname[x].toString();
var lname = lastname[x].toString();
// Logger.log(lname);

}

for (var y=0; y<firstname.length; y++) {
//var string = firstname[y].toString();
var fname = firstname[y].toString();
//  Logger.log(fname);

}

//var dept = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(37,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A37").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).setValues(department);
//Generate Drive ID

var newDrive = Drive.newTeamDrive();
var capabilities = Drive.newTeamDriveCapabilities();
capabilities.canAddChildren = true;
capabilities.canDownload = true;
capabilities.canEdit = true;
capabilities.canDeleteDrive = true;
capabilities.canManageMembers = true;
capabilities.canShare = true;

newDrive.capabilities = capabilities;
newDrive.name = 'CCW' + dept + '-' + fname + " " + lname;
var createdDrive = Drive.Drives.insert(newDrive, 'BCK' + Math.random());

//Add Managers on Drive  
var permission = Drive.newPermission();
permission.type = 'group';   //Type can be user, domain, group etc.. check role and type section at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/insert
permission.role = 'fileOrganizer';
permission.value = "xxxx@email.com";  //It can be email or domain or group name based on type 
Drive.Permissions.insert(permission, createdDrive.id, {
sendNotificationEmails:false,  //Make it true to send notification 
supportsTeamDrives:true,
useDomainAdminAccess:false
}); 

//---------------------Copying of Folders--------------------------------------
var sourcefolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1O1JSpx0-luxVW31b9Kmz4AYHwJe1dC77');
var destfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(createdDrive.id);
copyCustomFiles(sourcefolder, destfolder);
//---------------------Copying END----------------------------------

//Add User to Drive

var resource = {
'value': 'xxxx@email.com',
'type': 'group',
'role': 'organizer'
}
Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, createdDrive.id, {"supportsTeamDrives": true});

//End of Generate Drive ID 
Logger.log(createdDrive.id);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(37,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A37").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).setValues(createdDrive.id);
}
```

Also, I want to get all the Drive IDs inserted on the active sheet.

Expected output will be:

[image: Output]

Where MUR is the department, then Last Name and First Name. Those details must be from the cell values.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From your code I draw that the departments are listed in column A, starting with cell A1; the last name in column B, starting with B2, and the first name in column C, starting with C3. Is this correct? How is the correlation between departments and the corresponding names - they are not in the same row?

Comment: Hi, department will start at A1, lastname will be at B1, firstname will be at C1. Can I also fetch each DriveID of created drives with your code here?

Comment: Hi, I updated my code with your specifications.

Comment: Hi, thanks. but the code is only looping 2 times. I have 500 rows of data (dept, lname, fname) :(

Comment: If the code is looping only 2 times - maybe in the third row you have an empty cell which is interpreted as the end of an adjacent data range? In this case the problem will be solved my replacing `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow(),1).getValues()` through `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()` (same for the row numbers for `lastname` and `firstname`. If this does not solve the issue for you - I can have a look at your spreadsheet (just make sure to remove private information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I suggest you to modify your code by adding a `for` loop within which your nest the rest of your code and iterate through the array elements of your value arrays.

Sample:

```
function createDriveID(){
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var department = sheet.getRange(1,1,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow(),1).getValues();
var lastname = sheet.getRange(1,2,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow(),1).getValues();
var firstname = sheet.getRange(1,3,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C1").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow(),1).getValues();

for (var i=0; i<department.length; i++ ) {
  var dep = department[i][0].toString();
  var dept = dep.substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
  var lname = lastname[i][0].toString();
  var fname = firstname[i][0].toString();

  var newDrive = Drive.newTeamDrive();
  var capabilities = Drive.newTeamDriveCapabilities();
  capabilities.canAddChildren = true;
  capabilities.canDownload = true;
  capabilities.canEdit = true;
  capabilities.canDeleteDrive = true;
  capabilities.canManageMembers = true;
  capabilities.canShare = true;
  newDrive.capabilities = capabilities;
  newDrive.name = 'CCW' + dept + '-' + fname + " " + lname;
  var createdDrive = Drive.Drives.insert(newDrive, 'BCK' + Math.random());
  ...
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(createdDrive.id);
  }
}
```

> - Be aware that cell contents retrieved with `.getValues()` are stored in a 2-D array. Thus, to work with those values you need to specify
>     both dimesions, e.g. `var dep = department[i][0]`.
> - Assuming that the number of entries for department, lastname and firstname is equal and corresponds to the number of drives to create -
>     a single `for` loop is enough to iterate through all arrays
>     simultaneously.
> - Please see my comment to your question considering the correlation between >names and departments.